# Align local variable to 16-byte boundary (x86 asm)

Tags: assembly, x86, memory-alignment, callstack

I was having issues with allocating a 128-bit variable so that it is aligned on a 16-byte boundary (on the stack, not heap). I have no control over whether the stack will be aligned when my function is called so I'm just straight up assuming it's not.

Heres what my function looks like (simplified):

```
; start of stackframe
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

; space for our variable
sub esp, 0x10

; the 128-bit variable would be at [ebp - 0x10]
...

; end of stackframe
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
```

Now I could get the variable to be aligned by inserting `and esp, 0xFFFF'FFF0` before the `sub esp, 16` but then I would no longer be able to reference it with `[ebp - 0x10]` since `ebp` would be referring to the old, unaligned stack pointer.

Taking this in mind I figured that I would need to align the stack before the `mov ebp, esp` instruction so that I would be able to just manually align my variable. So in this example:

```
; align esp
and esp, 0xFFFF'FFF0

; start of stackframe
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

; padding (because of the push ebp)
sub esp, 0xC

; space for our variable
sub esp, 0x10

; the 128-bit variable would be at [ebp - 0x10]
...

; end of stackframe
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
```

The issue is that we wouldn't be properly cleaning up the stack at the end of the stackframe (not sure thought). This is because we do `mov ebp, esp` after we align the stack.

I can't really think of a nice way to do this. I feel like this should be a common problem due to sse alignment requirements but I couldn't find much info on the topic. Also remember, I have no control over the stack before my function is called as this is shellcode.

Edit:
I guess one solution would sorta be to wrap my stackframe in another stackframe. So something like this:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

; align the stack
and esp, 0xFFFF'FFF0

; the "real" stackframe start
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

; padding due to the push ebp prior to this
sub esp, 0xC

; space for our variable
sub esp, 0x10

; our variable is now at [ebp - 0x1C] (i think)
...

; the "real" stackframe end
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp

mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**After aligning the stack, reference locals relative to ESP.**  Or if you don't need many integer regs, possibly just align EDI or something instead of ESP itself, and access memory relative to that.

```
   push  ebp
   mov   ebp, esp     ; or any register, doesn't really matter

   and  esp, -16      ; round ESP down to a multiple of 16, reserving 0 to 12 bytes
   sub  esp, 32       ; reserve 32 bytes we know are there for sure.

   mov  dword [esp+4], 1234  ; store a local

   xorps  xmm0,xmm0
   movaps [esp+16], xmm0     ; zero 16 bytes of space with an aligned store

   leave            ; mov esp, ebp ; pop ebp
   ret
```

If you push args before a function call, remember that changes ESP temporarily. 
 You might simplify by reserving enough space up front as part of an initial `sub` and simply store args with `mov`, like GCC does with `-faccumulate-outgoing-args`

---

If you need access to incoming function args on the stack, you can still access *them* relative to EBP.

There are lots of ways to solve this problem depending on what you still need access to and what you don't.  e.g. after aligning the stack you could stash the pointer to the pre-aligned value in memory somewhere, freeing up all 7 other registers.  (In that case, you could load any stack args into registers *before* aligning the stack, so you don't need to keep a pointer to the top of your stack frame.)

---

**Look at clang output, or GCC8 and later, when compiling C or C++ with `alignas(32)` for locals, e.g. on https://godbolt.org/.**  Those compilers (with `-O2`) do what I suggested and reference locals relative to ESP after aligning the stack.

The standard 32-bit Linux calling convention aligns ESP by 16 before a `call` pushes a return address, so a simple `sub` can always reach a known alignas(16) boundary.  Depending on how your shellcode is reached, you might not be able to take advantage of that even if exploiting code that does have that guarantee.  e.g. the `ret` at the end of a vulnerable function will restore 16-byte stack alignment if this is a classic code-injection exploit of a buffer overflow, simply overwriting the return address with a pointer directly to your code.  Not a chain of return addresses for a ROP attack.

Anyway, that's why you should use a higher `alignas` if you want to see how compilers handle it.  The compilers on Godbolt other than MSVC are installed to target Linux.  Many other 32-bit ABIs only guarantee 4-byte stack alignment.

---

In shellcode it might make more sense to just use `movups` loads and stores and not bother with stack alignment.  Even though that means you can't use memory source operands unless you use the AVX version.  e.g. `paddd xmm0, [esp+16]` could fault if ESP isn't aligned by 16, but `movups xmm1, [esp+16]` can't.  And neither can `vpaddd xmm0, xmm0, [esp+16]`

You'll have to decide whether separate load instructions cost you more payload size than the prologue.

Also, `[ESP]` addressing modes always require a SIB byte, costing you 1 extra byte of code-size.  So that's one downside.  For performance saving uops is often worth it, but for code-size it can be worth using the 3-byte setup sequence of `push reg` / `mov reg, esp`.

---

**If you don't need to return, just `and esp, -16` and forget about it!**  e.g. do this at the very top of your shellcode, to whatever alignment you want, then take advantage of it for any calls/rets inside your payload.  The entry point of your exploit isn't going to `ret` (right?), and you usually don't care what was on the stack above it, so you don't need to preserve the old value.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I was hoping to still be able to use ebp to reference my local variables since tracking esp after pushes and pops gets pretty confusing. Also I don't have control over whether `movaps` or `movups` is used. Basically the situation is that im allocating this shellcode in a game's process and calling one of the game's functions. The function uses sse and requires that I pass a pointer to a structure that needs to be 16-byte aligned. Also this shellcode isn't really for an exploit, I have a lot of control over it (virtually unlimited size etc...)

Comment: @jono Ah, that makes a lot more sense than anything I was imagining.  I was in the middle of an update when you commented; added a few more suggestions.  You can use any register you want as a base pointer; if you can spare a couple regs you can have one track the ESP on entry and another as a base.  And re: ESP moving: maybe you missed the `-faccumulate-outgoing-args` style of code-gen where ESP doesn't move after a `sub` and you just use `mov` instead of `push` to store function args.  (Also, try it with a simple pair of functions with `__attribute__((noinline))`; it's a GCC option.)

Comment: oh thats actually pretty interesting, never thought of it that way. So basically i just `sub esp, x` once at the top and just mov data into `[esp + x]` to pass arguments to functions? And that way there's no headache with trying to track down `push`es and `pop`s. Awesome.

Comment: @jono: If this is code-injection into an executable to modify its behaviour instead of take over and get a shell, it isn't *really* shellcode.  It's just modifying a game executable or process.  Shellcode implies (to me at least) that it doesn't return (so you can just `and esp, -16` / `mov ebp, esp` up front);  if you're just diverting execution through some code you added, that's not shellcode.

Comment: @jono If it's not for an exploit, it's not really shellcode, it's just machine code.

Comment: yeah it's not really shellcode in that sense, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @jono: yes, sub once, then `[esp + x]`.  Another thing you can do is `mov eax, esp` before you start pushing, then use EAX as a frame pointer temporarily.  It's call-clobbered so you don't have to save/restore it before using.  Ideal if your wrapper only makes the one function call.